# Fastest way to gather facts to fact cache

Tags: caching, ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to make Ansible work with --limit and to do that I need facts about other hosts, which I am caching with fact_caching. What command should I run so that it simply gathers all the facts on all the hosts and caches them, without running any tasks? Something like the [setup module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/setup_module.html) would be perfect if it cached the facts it gathered, but it seems like it does not.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here is how I'd solve the problem:

1.- Enable facts gathering on your playbook (site.yml):

```
gather_facts: yes
```

2.- Enable [facts caching](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching) on ansible.cfg:

2.1.- Option 1 - Use this if you have the time to install redis:

```
[defaults]
gathering = smart
fact_caching = redis

# two hours timeout
fact_caching_timeout = 7200
```

2.2.- Option 2 - Use this to test right now is simple but slower than redis:

```
[defaults]
gathering = smart
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/facts_cache

# two hours timeout
fact_caching_timeout = 7200
```

3.- Update or create the facts cache. To do this create a new role (cache-update) with just one task: execute **ping**. We use ping because is the simplest and fastest ansible task so it will help us update the cache really fast:

```
- name: Pinging server to update facts cache
  ping:
```

Greetings,

Comment: I had already done the rest, but the ping command was what I was looking for. Also, gather_facts is yes by default.

Comment: How would I create a ping that pings all the servers in our inventory?

Comment: Easy: 
1) set: "hosts: all" on your site.yml
2) set: "roles: cache-update" on your site.yml

When executed it will run the ping task of your rol on all your hosts.

Comment: "gathering = smart" was unclear to me - this enables cache (the default is "implicit" which disables it: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-gathering .

Answer (score 4):

Creating a new playbook with only one line:

```
- hosts: all
```

and running it collects all the facts, and if fact_caching is on, it will cache them for use in future playbooks with --limit.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example showing how to use `/usr/bin/ansible` to run an ad-hoc task which gathers facts and stores them in the directory specified.

```
$ ANSIBLE_CONFIG=facts.cfg ansible r4i1 -i lab -m setup
```

Here's the contents of `facts.cfg`

```
[defaults]
gathering = smart
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /home/lab/facts
```

And an example host's output

```
$ head /home/lab/facts/r4i1 
{
    "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
        "10.10.20.89"
    ], 
    "ansible_all_ipv6_addresses": [
        "fe80::46a8:42ff:fe18:141c"
    ], 
    "ansible_apparmor": {
        "status": "disabled"
    },
```

Comment: despite what the OP said about it not working using the setup module in ad-hoc fashion, this is exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute fastest way would be to make use of Ansible's [fact caching](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching) that was introduced in version 1.8.  It requires the use of a redis server to store facts, but it will let you store facts between playbook runs.  As the documentation describes:

> Imagine, for instance, a very large infrastructure with thousands of hosts. Fact caching could be configured to run nightly, but configuration of a small set of servers could run ad-hoc or periodically throughout the day. With fact-caching enabled, it would not be necessary to “hit” all servers to reference variables and information about them.

The problem with --limit is that it will limit all the hosts that you ansible will interact with, so it will limit even what special host group like `all` will impact.  If you didn't use --limit but instead used host groups then you could do something like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks: []

- hosts: my_host_group
  tasks:
  - name: task1
    ...
  - name: task2
    ...
```

In this example, the first play would force the gathering of facts for all the hosts you have since you specified `hosts: all`.  The second play would then perform the desired tasks on the hosts in the group `my_host_group`.

Comment: I have already enabled fact caching (via json rather than redis), and we already use host groups. We also use --limit sometimes. I was looking for some way to update the fact cache without running the entire playbook.

Comment: Can you use a simple playbook with just running the `setup`, and target `all` hosts?  That way your facts are all cached without any updates made to the system.